How to write an undo-compatible python function to create a cube without using bpy.ops?
I'd like to make a blender python function that creates a mesh cube efficiently (i.e. without calling anything from bpy.ops),
using the technique described in this answer:
that is, copy an existing template object.
The caller of the function should not have to manage, or know about,
the template object; that should be a private implementation detail.
Here is my attempt:
import bpy
from mathutils import Vector

_template_cube = None
def PrimitiveCubeAddNotHorriblySlowly():
  global _template_cube
  if _template_cube is None:
    bpy.ops.mesh.primitive_cube_add()
    _template_cube = bpy.context.object  # the newly created cube
    _template_cube.name = "_template_cube"
    # Make template object invisible
    _template_cube.hide_set(True)

  new_cube = _template_cube.copy()
  new_cube.data = new_cube.data.copy()  # also duplicate mesh (remove for linked duplicate)

  # Change name and visibilty from those of the template.
  new_cube.name = "Cube"  # this may turn into "Cube.001" or etc., as usual
  new_cube.hide_set(False)
   
  bpy.context.scene.collection.objects.link(new_cube)
      
  # If this is used as a drop-in replacement for bpy.ops.curve.primitive_cube_add(),
  # then subsequent operations may assume the new object is the only selected one
  # and is active; so make it so.
  for o in bpy.context.selected_objects[:]:
    o.select_set(False)
  new_cube.select_set(True)
  bpy.context.view_layer.objects.active = new_cube
  # (that sets bpy.context.object and bpy.context.active_object,
  # both of which are read-only)

  return new_cube

# Use the function to make 1024 cubes...
for i in range(-48, 48, 3):
    for j in range(-48, 48, 3):
        another_cube = PrimitiveCubeAddNotHorriblySlowly()
        another_cube.location += Vector((i, j, 0))
      
bpy.context.view_layer.update() # don't place this in either of the above loops!

This works and is fast (.086s vs 12.39s for bpy.ops.mesh.primitive_cube_add(), i.e. 144x speedup, in this case; even more dramatic when there are more objects added, or in the scene already).
But there is a problem: if I run the calling code, then Undo and run it again, the template_cube.copy() fails with message:
ReferenceError: StructRNA of type Object has been removed

I understand why the failure happens: the function is trying to use the non-None _template_cube which is no longer valid after the Undo.
My question is: is there a way to rewrite this function in a way that is compatible with Undo?
One possible solution: put a try/except around the new_cube = _template_cube.copy(), and if a ReferenceError is caught, discard the template object.
But that seems kind of brutish; is there a cleaner / more standard way to maintain an Undo-friendly cache like this?
MCVE
Unfortunately, demonstrating the failure isn't trivial:
the failure does not happen if you just run the code above from the script editor, undo, and re-run it, since re-running the script gets a clean set of global variables each time.
So, to reproduce the failure, you have to do the action/undo/redo all without reloading the script. The following script sets that up, by making a custom ui button that does the action.  Follow the instructions at the top of the script.
This is the simplest reproducer I could think of.  If anyone has a simpler one, please let me know.
# MCVE for https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/326410/how-to-write-an-undo-compatible-python-function-to-create-a-cube-without-using-b
# 1. Run this script in the blender script editor, or run blender as:
#          blender --python this_script.py
#      It creates a panel "My custom panel" in UI category "My custom category"
#      in the right sidebar of the 3D View.
# 2. Expand that panel, and click on the "Create 1024 cubes the fast way" button.
#      It should create 1024 cubes.
# 3. Undo; the cubes disappear.
# 4. Click the button again.  It fails with:
#      ReferenceError: StructRNA of type Object has been removed

import bpy
from mathutils import Vector
import sys
import time

_template_cube = None
def PrimitiveCubeAddNotHorriblySlowly():
  global _template_cube
  if _template_cube is None:
    print("  CREATING TEMPLATE CUBE")
    bpy.ops.mesh.primitive_cube_add()
    _template_cube = bpy.context.object  # the newly created cube
    _template_cube.name = "_template_cube"
    # Make template object invisible
    _template_cube.hide_set(True)

  new_cube = _template_cube.copy()
  new_cube.data = new_cube.data.copy()  # also duplicate mesh (remove for linked duplicate)

  # Change name and visibilty from those of the template.
  new_cube.name = "Cube"  # this may turn into "Cube.001" or etc., as usual
  new_cube.hide_set(False)

  bpy.context.scene.collection.objects.link(new_cube)

  # If this is used as a drop-in replacement for bpy.ops.curve.primitive_cube_add(),
  # then subsequent operations may assume the new object is the only selected one
  # and is active; so make it so.
  for o in bpy.context.selected_objects[:]:
    o.select_set(False)
  new_cube.select_set(True)
  bpy.context.view_layer.objects.active = new_cube
  # (that sets bpy.context.object and bpy.context.active_object,
  # both of which are read-only)

  return new_cube


# Create the operator to be run by the first button.
class MESH_OT_create_1024_cubes_the_slow_way(bpy.types.Operator):
  """Create 1024 cubes the slow way (using bpy.ops.mesh.primitive_cube_add())"""  # button tooltip
  bl_idname = "mesh.create_1024_cubes_the_slow_way"
  bl_label = "Create 1024 cubes the slow way"  # button label
  bl_options = {'REGISTER', 'UNDO'}
  def execute(self, context):
    self.report({'INFO'}, "creating 1024 cubes the slow way")  # unfortunately does not show up immediately in INFO area
    print("creating 1024 cubes the slow way")  # so we see something on terminal window immediately
    t0 = time.time()
    for i in range(-48, 48, 3):
      for j in range(-48, 48, 3):
        bpy.ops.mesh.primitive_cube_add()
        another_cube = bpy.context.object  # the newly created cube
        another_cube.location += Vector((i, j, 0))
    t1 = time.time()
    print(f"created 1024 cubes the slow way in {t1-t0:.6f}s")
    self.report({'INFO'}, f"created 1024 cubes the slow way in {t1-t0:.6f}s")
    return {'FINISHED'}

# Create the operator to be run by the second button.
class MESH_OT_create_1024_cubes_the_fast_way(bpy.types.Operator):
  """Create 1024 cubes the fast way (using PrimitiveCubeAddNotHorriblySlowly()).  Not undo friendly!"""  # button tooltip
  t0 = time.time()
  bl_idname = "mesh.create_1024_cubes_the_fast_way"
  bl_label = "Create 1024 cubes the fast way"  # button label
  bl_options = {'REGISTER', 'UNDO'}
  def execute(self, context):
    self.report({'INFO'}, "creating 1024 cubes the fast way")  # unfortunately does not show up immediately in INFO area
    print("creating 1024 cubes the fast way")  # so we see something on terminal window immediately
    t0 = time.time()
    for i in range(-48, 48, 3):
      for j in range(-48, 48, 3):
        another_cube = PrimitiveCubeAddNotHorriblySlowly()
        another_cube.location += Vector((i, j, 0))
    bpy.context.view_layer.update()  # don't place this in either of the above loops!
    t1 = time.time()
    print(f"created 1024 cubes the fast way in {t1-t0:.6f}s")
    self.report({'INFO'}, f"created 1024 cubes the fast way in {t1-t0:.6f}s")
    return {'FINISHED'}

# Create the panel with the two buttons.
class VIEW3D_PT_my_custom_panel(bpy.types.Panel):  # class naming convention 'CATEGORY_PT_name'
  # where to add the panel in the UI
  bl_space_type = "VIEW_3D"
  bl_region_type = "UI"

  # add labels
  bl_category = 'My custom category' # found in the right sidebar (instead of "Misc")
  bl_label = 'My custom panel'  # found at the top of of the Panel

  def draw(self, context):
    row = self.layout.row()
    row.operator("mesh.create_1024_cubes_the_slow_way")
    row = self.layout.row()
    row.operator("mesh.create_1024_cubes_the_fast_way")

bpy.utils.register_class(MESH_OT_create_1024_cubes_the_slow_way)
bpy.utils.register_class(MESH_OT_create_1024_cubes_the_fast_way)
bpy.utils.register_class(VIEW3D_PT_my_custom_panel)
```


Here's a way to avoid invalid pointer:
https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/315994/reallocates-a-dead-pointer-object

@XY I'm finding all documentation and references to bpy.props.PointerProperty, including the one you pointed to, to be as clear as mud.  If you have an answer in mind, would it be possible for you to spell it out?  I'm guessing it's a 1- or 2-line replacement of something in my script.

I can't reproduce this on Blender 4.3β: run the script (cubes appear), ctrl+z (cubes disappear), run the script again (cubes appear again). Also, What I would do, is simply not store a reference on _template_cube between script executions, just on each execution of code set it it to bpy.data.object['some_unique_name']

@MarkusvonBroady ah I see, yes, if run from the script editor, it works properly, as you said, because re-running the script starts with a clean set of global variables.  The situation in which I run into the failure is when I have that calling code (which calls the function 1024 times) in the execute() method of a custom action run by a custom button in a custom panel.   Press the custom button, ctrl-z to undo, and press the button again; that's when it fails.     (I should probably edit the question to make this clear.)

@MarkusvonBroady If I understand correctly, you're suggesting the function PrimitiveCubeAddNotHorriblySlowly() should test for existence ofbpy.data.object['some_unique_name']; if it doesn't exist then create it, and if it does exist then reuse it?  Yes, I like that answer (better than the bpy.props.PointerProperty answer, in fact, since it seems simpler... it does clutter the objects set and is visible in the outliner, though, which I guess has advantages and disadvantages).  I had thought of this answer too and was going to write it up;  if you want to write it up then I'll accept it.

Added MCVE (it creates a button to do/redo the action without reloading the script, as I described above).

I think it won't appear in the outliner if it 's not added to any collection?

@MarkusvonBroady bpy.ops.mesh.primitive_cube_add() does add it to a collection, apparently.  I guess that could be avoided by creating the template using bpy.data.objects.new() instead of bpy.ops.mesh.primitive_cube_add(), as in XY's first script below, but that, too, would have advantages and disadvantages.  Or, I could remove it from the collection after the fact using 'bpy.context.scene.collection.objects.unlink(_template_cube)`, which does remove it from the outliner (and apparently hides it as well, thus removing the need for explicitly hiding the template and then unhiding the copies).

Argh, actually bpy.ops.mesh.primitive_cube_add() doesn't necessarily add it to bpy.context.scene.collection.objects, sometimes it adds it to some other collection(s?); at this moment I'm not sure how it decides.  So I'd have to figure out how to remove it from that other collection(s), and, if I still want to try to mimic bpy.ops.mesh.primitive_cube_add()'s behavior when making the copy (which is getting less and less appealing, TBH), I'd have to add the copy to that other collection(s).

Add a Cube to bpy.data.objects and assign to pointer proprety
import bpy

bpy.types.WindowManager.template_cube = bpy.props.PointerProperty(type=bpy.types.Object)

if bpy.context.window_manager.template_cube is None:

    verts = [
        (-1, -1, -1),
        (-1, +1, -1),
        (+1, +1, -1),
        (+1, -1, -1),
        (-1, -1, +1),
        (-1, +1, +1),
        (+1, +1, +1),
        (+1, -1, +1),
    ]

    edges = [[]]
    faces = [
        [0, 1, 2, 3],
        [0, 1, 5, 4],
        [1, 2, 6, 5],
        [2, 3, 7, 6],
        [0, 3, 7, 4],
        [4, 5, 6, 7],
    ]

    mesh = bpy.data.meshes.new(name="Cube Mesh")
    mesh.from_pydata(verts, edges, faces)
    cube = bpy.data.objects.new("Cube", mesh)
    bpy.context.window_manager.template_cube = cube


Change first 8 lines
import bpy
from mathutils import Vector

bpy.types.WindowManager.template_cube = bpy.props.PointerProperty(type=bpy.types.Object)
def PrimitiveCubeAddNotHorriblySlowly():
    if bpy.context.window_manager.template_cube is None:
        bpy.ops.mesh.primitive_cube_add()
        bpy.context.window_manager.template_cube = bpy.context.object
        _template_cube = bpy.context.object  # the newly created cube


Thanks fot the first "Add a Cube to bpy.data.objects and assign to pointer property""example:  from that, I can see how to rewrite PrimitiveCubeAddNotHorriblySlowly() using a bpy.props.PointerProperty instead of a python variable, so it will be undo-friendly, which answers my question.   It's not clear to me what the intent is of your second "Add 1000 cubes to the scene" example though-- it doesn't seem relevant to the question (which is: how to implement the encapsulated PrimitiveCubeAddNotHorriblySlowly() function, making it so the caller doesn't need to think about the template object).

Changing the first 8 lines should work, give it a try.

@X Y I don't understand what you're saying in your last comment.  I do apprecate your first example that shows how to use bpy.props.PointerProperty, which connects the dots so I could write a solution.  But, beyond that, I haven't been able to follow anything else you've said, in your answer or comment.

@X Y oh, sorry, I missed the fact that you edited your answer to show how my function should be rewritten!  Thanks.

@X Y your "Change first 8 lines" example code which you added works nicely. I'm still not sure what the purpose is of your final "Add 1000 cube to scene" code snippet is, though.  Maybe you could remove that?  (Or maybe replace it with the full file showing your fixed function and example of its use, which can be copy-pasted into the script editor-- that would be useful)

Just extra example, can be ignored.
